# Text is wrapping or floating below the img

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display the text next to the `img` but the text goes below the image when the size of the container decreases.

**HTML:**

```
 <ul>
     <li>
        <img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=api.jquery.com" /> 
        <div> <a href="#" >.append() | jQuery API Documentation </a> </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.links { 
   width:100px; 
   font-size: 10px; 
   cursor: pointer; 
   display: block;
}

li {
   overflow:auto; 
   word-wrap:break-word; 
}

img {float:left;}

li div {float:left;}

a { 
    color:blue; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    background: white; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

in the code above the the text in the `a` tag is  not supposed to go below the image. However, when I resize the container it goes below the image. what should I do to keep it next to the image. Also I don't want it to wrap.

Comment: And what you need when `UL` width is lower than children widths? Basic behavior for floated elements. You can't show `div` near `img` if there is not enough space.

Comment: Yes.. know that but I don't float then how do I do it.. inline-block also seems to be not working

Comment: Your inline CSS syntax is invalid in spots, just to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample below should work. You may want to properly align the code though. It's messy. I just used a "display: inline-block;" property on the image.

edit: I made the code block look nicer too. Here is a JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/mrykqafg/1/

```
<ul style="width: 230px; font-size: 10px; cursor: pointer; display: block;" class="links">
     <li style='overflow:auto; word-wrap:break-word; '>
        <div style="width: 230px;">
            <div style="width: 49%;">
                <img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=api.jquery.com"
                    style="float:left; display: inline-block;">
            </div>
            <div style="width: 49%; padding-left: 30px">
                 <a href="" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer; 
                background: white; vertical-align:top;">
                .append() | jQuery API Documentation
            </a>
            </div>
        </div>           
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: okay.. so margin or padding is a must.. I was avoiding this either.. :)

Comment: @whatever yep. You can display them inline and add a margin just to the image, but since you have a fixed width you want to work with, I'd recommend just breaking them up into nested divs. It would work better on all devices.

Comment: Oh. Then simply add a "margin-right" property to the image and use the "display: inline-block;" property on both the link and image.

Comment: I was checking the `facebook` comments portion and there they did it without applying margin or padding...

Comment: @whatever how did they do it?

Comment: I am checking for margins or padding but there are non... its looks like to be using floats.. but can't understand how they have achieved that effect...

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: table[-cell]` instead of `float`.

```
li {display: table}
li > * {display: table-cell}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2qn05tu/1/

Comment: Yes I know that .. but I wanted to try the float anyway... Just taking it as a challenge.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a float left, try this one:

```
/* Add class 'links' to the ul */
    .links {
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
    }

    li {
        overflow: auto;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    img {
        float: left;
    }

    div {
        display: inline;
    }

    a {
        color: blue;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: white;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```